# How to create slugs in arabic characters in Django?

Tags: python, django, unicode, slug

I am wondering how to make slugs out of Arabic/Persian strings in django? What I am trying to achieve is to create slugs like:

```
این-یک-تیتر-است
```

out of `این یک تیتر است`

That is, all spaces, commas and parentheses need to be converted to hyphens.

Comment: What happens when you use`slugify`? Is the output unchanged? Are all non-latin characters stripped?

Comment: What? No! Make your question self-contained. Show what youve tried.

Comment: Go back, read my first comment and answer the questions I asked. Can you show us exactly what happens when you try `slugify` using arabic letters? I don't have the ability to type them. Show us some attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, thanks python's excellent string library, turned out to be easier than what I thought. Just need to define a function like this:

```
def slugify(str):
    str = str.replace(" ", "-")
    str = str.replace(",", "-")
    str = str.replace("(", "-")
    str = str.replace(")", "")
    str = str.replace("؟", "")
    return str
```

Then in your model's class you should have a function like:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
```

**Note:**
This line should be present at the beginign of the module.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

otherwise you may get an error like:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character ...
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [awesome-slugify](https://pypi.org/project/awesome-slugify/)

```
from slugify import  slugify_unicode
print(slugify_unicode('این یک تیتر است'))
```